# Error with DateUtil.Parser : cannot import name 'isoparse'

Tags: python, python-dateutil

I am trying to execute the following code, but I get the error "ImportError: can not import name 'isoparse'". I tried installing python-dateutil but the error persist.

The code is from https://github.com/yannforget/pylandsat

```
from datetime import datetime

import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Point
from pylandsat import Catalog, Product

catalog = Catalog()

begin = datetime(2000, 1, 1)
end = datetime(2010, 1, 1)
geom = Point(4.34, 50.85)

# Results are returned as a pandas dataframe
scenes = catalog.search(
    begin=begin,
    end=end,
    geom=geom,
    sensors=['ETM', 'LC08']
)

# Get the product ID of the scene with the lowest cloud cover
scenes = scenes.sort_values(by='cloud_cover', ascending=True)
product_id = scenes.index[0]

# Download the scene
product = Product(product_id)
product.download(out_dir='data')
```

And the error is :

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-83e3395a0606> in <module>()
      3 import pandas as pd
      4 from shapely.geometry import Point
----> 5 from pylandsat import Catalog, Product
      6 
      7 catalog = Catalog()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pylandsat/__init__.py in <module>()
      5 
      6 from pylandsat.scene import Scene
----> 7 from pylandsat.catalog import Catalog
      8 from pylandsat.download import Product

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pylandsat/catalog.py in <module>()
      6 
      7 from pylandsat import queries
----> 8 from pylandsat.database import LandsatDB
      9 
     10 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pylandsat/database.py in <module>()
      6 import csv
      7 from datetime import datetime
----> 8 from dateutil.parser import isoparse
      9 import os
     10 import shutil

ImportError: cannot import name 'isoparse'
```

Comment: This looks like a bug in pylandsat. They did not specify their dependency correctly. You can fix it by updating python-dateutil.

Comment: Hi @Paul I´m using python-dateutil 2.8.0 by Pip but the error persist.